# How do I add a UIBarButtonItem to a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Prior to iOS 8 I could simply drag the UIBarButtonItem from the object library to a navigation bar. But now I simply can't if it is not the first view controller on the navigation stack.

I know I can do it in code but is there any way I can make it happen in Storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. First drag-drop a `UINavigationItem` to your ViewController. This will add a title bar. Then drag a `UIBarButtonItem` and drop in the nav bar. This works.